# Gparted and Synaptic ask for root password instead of mine

Tags: linux, password, root, raspbian, synaptic

I've just installed Synaptic and Gparted on my Raspbian Lite. However I can't use them when launching from the desktop. They ask me for the root password which... there isn't.

I have no problem launching them from a terminal using `sudo` but seems a bit stupid having to use a command to launch a GUI application when they have a perfectly fine GUI executable.

What can I do so they ask me for my password instead of root's?

EDIT:

Finally, what I've have done in order to avoid having the root account enabled is editing the `.desktop` files.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/synaptic.desktop
```

And changed the line that says:

```
 Exec=synaptic-pkexec
```

to:

```
Exec=sudo synaptic-pkexec
```

Now it doesn't ask for password if the user has sudo privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gparted attempts to elevate itself when it starts via [polkit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html), which prompts you for some authentication through whatever polkit agent you're using
It seems Synaptic also uses polkit

Your options are:

- Add yourself to the `wheel` group with `$ sudo usermod -aG wheel [user]`

  - log out and in again
  - polkit *should* now ask for you own password
- Change the way polkit behaves, eg [no authentication](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98006), or [other options](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit#Configuration)
- Set the root password via `$ sudo passwd root`, to your own user's password perhaps

  - you might have to first unlock the root user through `$ sudo passwd -u root`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Changing the password did the trick. However I am surprised that the people from the distro hadn't fixed that.